# Entering the UK in transit to Italy before UK visa entry date

Tags: ancestry-visas

I am a New Zealand citizen with a UK Ancestry visa (5 years) with entry date into the UK being 1 May 2017.

I am planning to travel to Italy before arriving from New Zealand into the UK, however the best available flights take me to London first on 24 April 2017, from where I will fly out to Italy and then back to London on 1 May 2017 being the entry date on my visa.

The flights are not connecting, they are individual tickets.

Will arriving in the UK before my visa entry date, despite the fact that I will be flying out to Italy the same day and then re-entering the UK on my visa entry date, cause any issues?

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be a problem. As a New Zealand citizen, you don't need a visa for transit in the UK, or even to enter for up to six months, so the fact that your visa isn't yet valid on April 24th doesn't matter.